# 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto' System.FormatException

Tags: c#

estoy creando un programa de stock en C#, y, cuando estoy ejecutando el programa, quiero agregar un producto y  me deja, pero intento nuevamente agregar otro producto y me salta el error que me lleva directamente al codigo. dejo una imagen para que lo miren.

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Altamente probable que el problema está en tus funciones Convert... ¿Estás seguro que los cuadros de texto no están vacíos?

Comment: Sisi los lleno todos, asi tambien me pasa con otras partes del codigo, estoy copiando y pegando el codigo en otros formularios, el error me salta en todos los formularios que tengo.

Comment: Evita adjuntar imágenes, estas deben ser solo ilustrativas al problema. [edit] tu pregunta y adjunta el código necesario para entender mejor tu problema.

Comment: Facundo Lopez sería interesante que publiques aquí la Excepción exacta (que línea e InnerException). También podrías publicar el código de todo el botón. Insisto en que el problema estaría en algún Cast que estás haciendo.